# What is Nassim Taleb's Stance on Volatility

Tags: volatility, reference-request

Over the years I have read all of Taleb's *Incerto*. I recall him more or less writing that "stock returns have no second moment". Hence stock volatilities, defined via the standard deviation are infinite. I also recall him saying that it is obvious that given a finite sample, an estimator of the standard deviation can be computed.

**I am looking for a reference of Taleb making this infinite-variance-of-returns-claim**. I have tried searching online, but haven't found exactly that.

Comment: I recall him talking about this in the Black-Swan. But the idea is usually attributed to Benoit Mandelbrot.

Comment: Taleb made a mathematical parallel version of his book collection *The Incerto*, which can be found freely available [here](http://datascienceassn.org/sites/default/files/Probability%20and%20Risk%20in%20the%20Real%20World.pdf). I haven't looked it through, but maybe he mathematically describes what he implies by *stock returns having  no second moment* (either directly or indirectly). If not, it is still a good additional read, when you have read his *Incerto* collection :-)